# How to set WebView Scroll as per dynamic content size without overlaying XAML Control in Windows Store App

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I was working on a project where I have to show the Dynamic HTML content on the Web View Control. Bt because of unexpected behavior of Web View control I was not able to add the Scroll value to it. I tried same with Scroll Viewer bt it was Overlaying the other XAML Control.

Than after doing lots of google search and self logic ... I came to the final solution and would like to share with you guys.

Below is the code for my Web View

---

```
WebView x:Name="WebView6" Margin="-8,0,0,0"  Grid.Row="1" Width="400" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Loaded="WebView_OnLoaded" 
        LoadCompleted="WebView_OnLoadCompleted" 
        conv:HtmlBinder.HTML="{Binding BriefDescription}"
```

Below is the code of my HTML Binder in Web View's Script Notify Event

---

```
static void webView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (sender != null)
                {
                    var webView = ((WebView)sender);
                    double contentHeight = Convert.ToDouble(e.Value) * 1.5;
                    double screenHeight = Window.Current.CoreWindow.Bounds.Height - 185;
                    webView.Height = contentHeight > screenHeight ? screenHeight : contentHeight;
                    webView.UpdateLayout();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post your solution as an answer below.